# Error assigning query results to a variable in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am having issues assigning a variable to a query result and then inserting the value of that variable in a table. The row is inserted into the table but the 'gPayRef' field (which is supposed to house the value of the variable) is null

This is my code:-

```
SET @eReceipt =
  (SELECT DISTINCT `gpayref`
  FROM `TRANSACTION`
  WHERE `ereceipt` = '12345');

INSERT INTO reversals (gpayref, reversalinitby, reversalinitdate, reason, status)
VALUES (@eReceipt,
    reversalinitby,
    Now(),
    reason,
      (SELECT id
       FROM `status`
       WHERE NAME = 'Reversal pending'));

SELECT Row_count() INTO res;
```

Comment: does `(SELECT DISTINCT `gPayRef` FROM `transaction` WHERE `eReceipt` = '12345')` return 1 value?

Comment: also verify the other sub select `(SELECT id FROM `status` WHERE NAME = 'Reversal pending')`

Comment: @KristjanKica Yes.

Comment: Where do you get values for `reversalinitby,  reason`??

Comment: Are you getting any error, as you stated in the title? Also, please post sample data of what you are trying to get into the variable and inserting into the table.

Comment: @KristjanKica, I didn't show that in the question. I can however confirm that that is not the problem.

Comment: I suggest, you give us more to work with, because i do not see anything else wrong. It may be something that you don't suspect.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fJoS25rmNuNdjcUHN4Fk7u/0).